# Groupby and generate a column saying how many values are imputed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Region | Country | Imputed | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | South Africa | No | 2016 | 500 |
| Africa | South Africa | No | 2017 | 400 |
| Africa | South Africa | Yes | 2018 | 432 |
| Africa | South Africa | No | 2019 | 450 |
| Africa | Nigeria | Yes | 2016 | 750 |
| Africa | Nigeria | Yes | 2017 | 780 |
| Africa | Nigeria | No | 2018 | 816 |
| Africa | Nigeria | No | 2019 | 890 |
| Africa | Kenya | Yes | 2016 | 212 |
| Africa | Kenya | No | 2017 | 376 |
| Africa | Kenya | No | 2018 | 415 |
| Africa | Kenya | No | 2019 | 430 |

Here is the sample data:

```
data1 = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa'],
         'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','Nigeria','Nigeria','Nigeria','Nigeria','Kenya','Kenya','Kenya','Kenya'],
         'Imputed': ['No','No','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','No','No','Yes','No','No','No'],
         'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
         'Price': [500, 400, 432,450,750,780,816,890,212,376,415,430]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

I have to do a `groupby` using `Region` and `Year` to calculate the regional price for each year, which is straightforward to do. However, I would like to add a new column which says how many values have been imputed when doing the `groupby`.

The output should look like this:

| Region | Imputed | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | 2/3 Components Imputed | 2016 | 487.3 |
| Africa | 1/3 Components Imputed | 2017 | 518.7 |
| Africa | 1/3 Components Imputed | 2018 | 554.3 |
| Africa | 0/3 Components Imputed | 2019 | 590 |

Below is my code so far:

```
df = df.groupby(['Region','Year'])['Price'].mean()
```

Is there any way of adding the additional column as per my desired output example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single-pass aggregation using `{'Yes':1, 'No':0}` mapping and string formatting:

```
df = df.groupby(['Region','Year'])\
    .agg({'Price': 'mean',
          'Imputed': lambda x: f"{x.map({'Yes':1, 'No':0}).sum()}/{x.size}"})\
    .reset_index()
```

---

```
   Region  Year       Price Imputed
0  Africa  2016  487.333333     2/3
1  Africa  2017  518.666667     1/3
2  Africa  2018  554.333333     1/3
3  Africa  2019  590.000000     0/3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper column with compare `Imputed` and for count `True`s aggregate by `sum`, for total cout use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) (and if necassary use `mean` for `Count_Imputed`), last join columns to `Imputed` and for expected order of columns use list:

```
df1 = (df.assign(Imputed = df['Imputed'].eq('Yes'))
       .groupby(['Region','Year'], as_index=False)
       .agg(Price=('Price','mean'),
            Imputed=('Imputed','sum'),
            new=('Imputed','size'),
            Count_Imputed=('Imputed','mean')))

df1['Imputed'] = (df1['Imputed'].astype(str) + '/' +
                 df1['new'].astype(str) + ' Components Imputed')

df1 = df1[['Region','Imputed','Count_Imputed','Year','Price']]
print (df1)
   Region                 Imputed  Count_Imputed  Year       Price
0  Africa  2/3 Components Imputed       0.666667  2016  487.333333
1  Africa  1/3 Components Imputed       0.333333  2017  518.666667
2  Africa  1/3 Components Imputed       0.333333  2018  554.333333
3  Africa  0/3 Components Imputed       0.000000  2019  590.000000
```